# setAttribute is not a function when referencing from a variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

I am working with a VueJS project where I have a `icon` variable that includes the inline SVG code. I'd like to add the `width` attribute to the `<svg></svg>` element dynamically from a computed property. However, even though I have the correct code for the SVG icon in the variable, the `setAttribute` isn't working and throwing the error. I'm not sure what I am missing here.

The following is from the Vue template where I want to show the inline SVG code:

```html
<code v-text="appendDimension"></code>
```

The following I have in the Vue single component:

```js
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      dimension: 50,
      icon: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M11 9h4v2h-4v4H9v-4H5V9h4V5h2v4zm-1 11a10 10 0 110-20 10 10 0 010 20zm0-2a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16z"/></svg>'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    appendDimension() {
      return this.icon.setAttribute("width", this.dimension);
    }
  }
};
```

I have created a test project on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-neumann-nl0nj) that you can use to reproduce it on your end. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried checking what `typeof this.icon` reports inside that `appendDimension()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this.icon` in that function is the **string** to which it was initialized in the `.data()` method. It's not an actual `<svg>` element.

Also, using `.setAttribute()` as the value of a `return` statement doesn't make a lot of sense anyway, as it always returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

Since the value of `this.icon` is a string you could change the string dynmically before you return it. Your computed method could look like this:

```
computed: {
    appendDimension() {   
      return this.icon.replace("<svg ", "<svg width='" + this.dimension + "' ");
    }
  }
```

You should also change your `<code v-text="appendDimension"></code>` to `<code v-html="appendDimension"></code>` since you want to render the html and not the string itself. But that's my guess ;)